# Why isn't the PHP imagettftext function working in this case?

Tags: php, html, image

Can anyone tell me why I can't use the function imagettftext when I'm trying to create a captcha? It works fine with imagestrings, but the font-size is to small so I have to use imagettftext... Is this a problem with Wamp or what is it? Thanks for your time!

PHP code(so far):

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-Type: image/png");

$text = $_SESSION['secure'];
$font_size = 30;

$image_width = 200;
$image_height = 40;

$image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);
imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, 'arial.ttf', $text);
imagepng($image);
?>
```

Index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['secure'] = rand(1000,9999);
?>

<img src="createanimage.php" />
```

Comment: What do you mean you "can't use it"? Can you post error-log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what little info you've given, the code initially didn't work for me, I changed the font path from `arial.ttf` to `./arial.ttf`. It worked!

An exact replica of your code: http://tekinozbek.net/so_imagettftext.php

**Beware** some spammers use image analysis to recognize text paths and determine the CAPTCHA image! I would certainly suggest you use something like [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) for better protection against spam.

Comment: I just got stuck at this point so I couldn't move on with it, but now  when I know the problem I can continue working on it. Thanks a lot!